# iOS-Charts - yAxis labels not start exactly at bottom

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I use Charts swift library in my project.I use two datasets in line chart, but the labels of Yaxis not start exactly at bottom.I want the first label on the yAxis to be exactly at bottom-left corner of chart. I try to set minimum of yAxis but it didn't help.

Following is example image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of `leftAxis.axisMinValue` on your `LineChartView` property, or whatever type of chart you are graphing. If you set it to 0, then the "0.0" in your chart will be positioned correctly at the very bottom.  You can set this to other values and the chart will start at those values too.

Here is a simple example of it in action:

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourChartViewController: LineChartView! // View controller for the chart in a storyboard.
// Set up your data for the chart...

// Configuring the chart's view
yourChartViewController.leftAxis.axisMinValue = 0  // This is what you need
```

Comment: Thank you, in my solution i find the minimum value of my data sets and set is as minimum at yAxis, everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Just set minimum value to 0, as below for leftAxis:

If you didn't find `axisMinValue` in your code

Use code as below:

```
@IBOutlet var chartView: BarChartView!

chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0 //Used to show yaxis lables to bottom
```